# UIButton backgroundRect(forBounds:) not being called

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a custom hexagon shaped button and I want to disable the background color so it wont create a square shape around the hexagon itself.
I am using the `backgroundRect(forBounds:)` method to override the background's rect.
Here is the full implementation:

```
class HexaButton : UIButton {
    var shape : CAShapeLayer!
    func setup() {
        if shape == nil {
            shape = CAShapeLayer()
            shape.fillColor = self.backgroundColor?.cgColor
            shape.strokeColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
            shape.lineWidth = 5.0
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
            self.layer.addSublayer(shape)
        }
        let side : CGFloat =  6
        let r =  frame.height/side
        shape.path = ShapeDrawer.polygonPath(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2, radius: r, sides: Int(side), pointyness: side/2.0)

    }
    override func backgroundRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return .zero
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if shape?.path?.contains(point) == true {
            return self
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

For some unknown reason, the `backgroundRect(forBounds:)` isn't being called.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `backgroundImage` property of your `UIButton` and `backgroundRect` method will be called.